# Installation of Skype 4.3.with Synaptic to Ununtu 14.10

Tags: software-installation, skype

My question is:

1. Installation of Skype 4.3.0.37... with Synaptic to Ubuntu 14.10 - does Skype work OK with this installation ?
2. In my Synaptic screenshot I see now following packets of Skype programs.

   ```
   Packet:                               Last version:
   skype                                 4.3.0.37-OubuntuO..
   pidgin-skype-dbg                      20130613+svn660+...
   emphaty-skype                         the same
   pidgin skype                          the same
   pidgin-skype-common                   the same
   ```

And my question is:

1. should I mark them ALL for installation or
2. only the first one (skype 4.3.0.37 ..) and other packets LATER, when Skype is already working OK? When I look these 4 small packets, Skynaptic indicates, that

   > This plugin communicates with the Skype application in the background to perform its work, so it's necessary to have Skype installed and running

   But, can Skype work even without these without these 4 small packets, if they are not installed simultaneously with skype packet installation?

Comment: Have you activated Canonical Partners and Universe + Multiverse in update sources, Skype uses i386 packs for sound.
Then it should work, my Skype is same vertion, from Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise with packet versions in the beginning. I  checked how Synaptic packet versions in full and it shows that, skype is version 4.3.0.37.OubuntuO.12.04.1 and the other packets are all 20130613+svn660+dfsg+1 . Doeas this mean that skype is only for Ubuntu 12.04 ? Brgs, Kauko

Comment: Your question re my repositories now:  I have 1.) Canonical Partners, 2.) Independent Developers and, 3.) Independent Developers (source code). I do not know how / from where to add  ''Universe + Multiverse'' repository. ? My Ubuntu 14.10 is in Finnnish language, so please excuse me, if these repository names of mine here are not correct in English versions of Ubuntu 14.10. Kauko

Comment: Short answer: Yes it does! Remember multiverse!
As saiarcot895 says in his answer Just install Skype, you can allways add the other packages later if you need them!
Happy Ubunting

Comment: To Ken Mollerup: Sorry for dealay, now I understood your question.  Yes, in my ''System Setting s'' in A.) '' Programs and Updates''-section I have had already activated  1.) Canonical Partners (main), 2.) Universe programs and 3.) Multiverse programs and 4.) Restricted drivers; and in B.)''Other programs'' -section I have had  1.) Canonical Partners, 2.) Independent Developers and, 3.) Independent Developers (source code).

Comment: To Ken Mollerup: Sorry for dealay,  now I understood your question.  Yes, in my ''System Setting s'' in A.) '' Programs and Updates''-section I have had (before this discussion) already activated:  1.) Canonical Partners (main), 2.) Universe programs and 3.) Multiverse programs and 4.) Restricted drivers; and in B.)''Other programs'' -section I have had  activated:1.) Canonical Partners, 2.) Independent Developers and, 3.) Independent Developers (source code). Maybe it is  therfore ( I think ?),  I get skype packet info also to my Synaptic.  Brdgs, Kauko Peltonen

Comment: Great then you are ready, just follow David Foerster's link. And if you dont already have Pidgin & Empathy installed just leave those packages for the day you decide which one you like and need.  Cheers Ken

Comment: I want to thank very much Ken Mollerup and David Foerster for help and concrete advices which helped me to install succesfully Skype 4.3. packet to my Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit with Synaptic, now I have installed and tested: result → all works OK (system, voice and camera). THANK YOU !!

Comment: Here is my short summary of the process and commands:  

A. System Settings → Ubuntu programs → choose following: Programs packed by Canonical (main) + universe + multiverse  ->
B. System Settings  → Other programs → choose applicatios of Canonical partners + Independent developers + Independent developers (source code) → 
C. Update your Ubuntu programs → 
D. Open Synaptic -> Update → Find 'skype' from 'Name'→ Mark for installation →select 'skype4.3.0.37OubuntuO12.04.1' packet → Execute → Wait → Open your Unity-box → Open Skype logo → Open/Create your Skype account  … etc → Now it works OK !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just install the main program (`skype`) without the other packages. The other packages are plugins for other chat applications (Pidgin and Empathy, in this case) to use Skype.

If you don't use Pidgin or Empathy, you won't gain anything by installing `pidgin-*` or `empathy-*`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is my short summary of installation:  

A. System Settings → Ubuntu programs → choose following: Programs packed by Canonical (main) + universe + multiverse  ->
B. System Settings  → Other programs → choose applicatios of Canonical partners + Independent developers + Independent developers (source code) → 
C. Update your Ubuntu programs → 
D. Open Synaptic -> Update → Find 'skype' from 'Name'→ Mark for installation →select 'skype4.3.0.37OubuntuO12.04.1' packet → Execute → Wait → Open your Unity-box → Open Skype logo → Open/Create your Skype account  etc→ it works OK !